# Is it possible to link two relationships in one column in typeorm?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm making a project using nestjs and typeorm.

I want to concatenate two `manyToOne` relationships in one column.

```js
@Entity()
export class CommonFile {
  @IsNumber()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @Column()
  parentId: number;

  @IsString()
  @Column()
  fileLink: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Notice, (notice) => notice.noticeFile, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
    name: 'parentId',
  })
  notice: Notice;

  @ManyToOne(() => Help, (help) => help.files, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
    name: 'parentId',
  })
  help: Help;
}
```

As above, I want to link the two relationships on the `parentId` column.

The reason for linking two in one column is that it originally had two entities. But I want to use it in one unified way.

The error code is `ER_FK_DUP_NAME`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: you can't, but you should duplicate the field with different name

Comment: @K.D It's impossible... Thank you for answer.!

Comment: How do `Notice` and `Help` relate to each other? Can you share these models as well?

Comment: @W.S. `help` and `notice` are not related to each other.